# Button Click Frequency Array

Tags: c#, arrays, button, listbox, frequency

I need to make a `ListBox` that displays how often a `Button` is clicked.

The user chooses how many buttons are available to click. Here is what I've tried:

```
int clicked;

clicked = int.Parse(((Button)(sender)).Text);

freq_array[clicked]++;

for (int i = 0; i < freq_array[clicked]; i++)
    lstFrequencies.Items[clicked] = clicked + "\t\t" + freq_array[clicked];
```

`freq_array` uses the 'clicked' variable to add to the frequency that button has been clicked. Or, it's supposed to.

When I debug it, 'clicked' always comes out to 0. I want 'clicked' to equal the text value of the button that's clicked. When I try to run the program, I get an error saying "Input string was not in correct format."

Edit:

I was able to fix my program with help from you guys. I realized I didn't show enough of my code to be clear enough, and I apologize for that. I had to add some things and move things around and got it soon enough. Thank you all.

Here is the code just for those who may need help in the future:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int[] freq_array = new int[11];
    int[] numList = new int[11];
    int oBase = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        invisiblity();
    }

    private void invisiblity()
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is Button)
                if (Char.IsDigit(ctrl.Text[0]))
                    ctrl.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    private void btnSetBase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frmDialog = new Form2();
        frmDialog.ShowDialog(this);

        if (frmDialog.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            oBase = frmDialog.Base;
            //lblOutDigits.Text = oBase.ToString();

            for (int i = 0; i < oBase; i++)
            {
                numList[i] = i;
            }
        }

        ShowBaseButtons(oBase);
    }

    private void ShowBaseButtons(int last_digit)
    {
        invisiblity();

        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is Button)
                if (Char.IsDigit(ctrl.Text[0]))
                    if (int.Parse(ctrl.Text) <= last_digit - 1)
                        ctrl.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    private void btnN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblOutDigits.Text += ((Button)(sender)).Text;

        int clicked = int.Parse(((Button)(sender)).Text);

        freq_array[clicked]++;
    }

    private void btnShowFreq_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstFrequencies.Items.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < oBase; i++)
        lstFrequencies.Items.Add(numList[i] + "  \t\t\t" + freq_array[i]);

    }
```

Comment: Is the button label a number?  If not, there's the problem as you are trying to convert it to a number.  Do a log on the value of the button's text to see exactly what you are dealing with, and consider switching to a hash table if you aren't using one already.

Comment: What is the text of the button?

Comment: All buttons are numbers, 0 - 10.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work as long as your Button Text is actually just a number. Since what you are trying to do is create an index, what I usually do is use the `Tag` Property of the control, set it to the Index I want in the designer and then cast that to an Int.

i.e.

```
if (int.TryParse(((Button)sender).Tag.ToString(), out clicked))
    freq_array[clicked]++;
```

---

I believe what is happening is that you are not initializing your ListBox, This example Code does work using your initial method. Just create a new Form and paste it in and test.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ListBox lstFrequencies = new ListBox();
    int[] freq_array = new int[10];
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Size = new Size(400, 400);
        lstFrequencies.Location = new Point(150, 0);
        lstFrequencies.Size = new Size(150, 200);
        Controls.Add(lstFrequencies);
        int top = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Size = new Size(70, 30);
            btn.Location = new Point(5, top);
            Controls.Add(btn);
            top += 35;
            btn.Tag = i;
            btn.Text = i.ToString();
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
            lstFrequencies.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }

    }

    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int clicked;

        clicked = int.Parse(((Button)(sender)).Text);

        freq_array[clicked]++;

        lstFrequencies.Items[clicked] = clicked + "\t\t" + freq_array[clicked]; //Cleaned up you do not need to iterate your list

        // Using my example code

        //if (int.TryParse(((Button)sender).Tag.ToString(), out clicked))
        //{
        //    freq_array[clicked]++;
        //    lstFrequencies.Items[clicked] = clicked + "\t\t" + freq_array[clicked];
        //} 
    }
}
```

Comment: "Object not set to an instance of an object"
Got this error. I have each button with the same tag.

Comment: @Bex See my correction, I just realized that it wasn't working

Comment: @Bex the above code works as long with your original code, I tested before I reposted

Comment: Well, I'll keep fixing things around. But, you did help a lot. Thank you~

Comment: Everything was created before the code was written. I'm using visual studio. So, before I even started coding, I had everything on the form.

Comment: @Bex I understand that, but to give a working standalone example without you having to assume what controls I used, I made it this way. This code works and will allow you hopefully to find the problem with yours. As I mentioned earlier you need to verify that your ListBox has the same number of items as you have buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Your code always comes out to 0 because you never assign last clicked value to button text. Try this code:

```
int clicked = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clicked = Convert.ToInt32(((Button)sender).Text);
    lstFrequencies.Items.Add(((Button)sender).Name + " " + ++clicked);
    button1.Text = clicked.ToString();  // you lose this line

}
```

EDIT: Counter from variable member

```
int clicked = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // if you want to display button name, change .Text to .Name
   lstFrequencies.Items.Add(((Button)sender).Text + " " + ++clicked);

}
```

Comment: He is not wanting to change his Button Text. The Text is just an Index so that he knows what value to increment.

Comment: He said "When I debug it, 'clicked' always comes out to 0. **I want 'clicked' to equal the text value of the button that's clicked**". I assume that **counter input comes from the text button**. Sorry if I misunderstood about question.

Comment: I can see why it would be confusing, it is actually being used as an index if you look more closely at his code. Index would probably be a more descriptive name.

Comment: Basically, if the user clicks the 5 button, I was the listbox to display the number 5, and beside it a number 1. If they click it again, 5 beside a number 2. If 7 times, 5 with a 7. And so on.